# Control number of threads in dotnet core's ThreadPool

Tags: c#, .net-core, threadpool

I'm running dotnet core version 2.1.3 on my MacOS and I've tried playing with the default threadpool with no success. I've tried to modify the number of threads in several ways (most of which I've googled):

**Program.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, 1);
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1, 1);
    DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

**.csproj**

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
  <ConcurrentGarbageCollection>true</ConcurrentGarbageCollection>
  <RetainVMGarbageCollection>true</RetainVMGarbageCollection>
  <ThreadPoolMinThreads>1</ThreadPoolMinThreads>
  <ThreadPoolMaxThreads>1</ThreadPoolMaxThreads>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Environment variables**

```
$ ComPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMinWorkerThreads=1 ComPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMaxWorkerThreads=1 dotnet run
```

None of these seem to have any effect:

```
$ ps -M 97046
USER           PID   TT   %CPU STAT PRI     STIME     UTIME COMMAND
XXX 97046 s002    0.0 S    31T   0:00.02   0:00.07 dotnet exec /XXX
             97046         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
             97046         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
             97046         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
             97046         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
             97046         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
             97046         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00 
             97046         0.0 S    31T   0:00.00   0:00.00
```

What am I missing here? Is that OS specific?

Comment: What makes you think the setting didn't work? You are aware that the setting affects only the size of the thread pool - not the number of threads that the program is allowed to use? _If you new up a thread directly, for example, that is over and above the thread pool limit._

Comment: Why would you need to modify the threads in the threadpool? How do you measure its size since you *haven't* used `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads()` or `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads()`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks states `You cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors on the computer.` How many processors are there on your computer?

Comment: BTW a value of 1 is a *very* unusual value - you are trying to shut the threadpool off. I wouldn't be surprised if the runtime refused to do this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The `ps -M` command (as you can see in my question) shows how many threads are running and on my machine: it is 8. And yes, I'm trying to make the threadpool basically single threaded to see how async stuff behaves. This is for testing/educational purposes.

Comment: @mjwills Hmm, that would explain it, I have 8 cores. The restriction is strange though.

Comment: @freakish that shows active threads, not the size of the threadpool. Use the correct methods. You'll see that the max limit is above 500

Comment: @freakish I have to ask why you want to manipulate the ThreadPool at all. What set of circumstances leads you to believe that this is the right corrective action? (hint: it probably isn't).

Comment: @freakish the restriction isn't strange at all. What good is a threadpool that can't use any cores? It's a thread*pool* not an array of active threads. In any case, the threadpool isn't used for *async* operations. Async operations typically don't use threads at all, they use the OS driver's asynchronous IO capabilities. *Callbacks* after an async operation do use threads from a threadpool

Comment: @freakish if you want to restrict the number of threads used for specific operations, use a custom TaskScheduler eg for Task.Run  or provide a DOP parameter eg for `Parallel.ForEach` or PLINQ. The *threadpool* is used by the entire process, ie used by all background, parallel and asynchronous operations and APIs

Comment: @spender Please read my comments. I'm doing some tests.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the hint, do you know something similar for MacOS?

Comment: Alas no. https://superuser.com/questions/149312/how-to-set-processor-affinity-on-os-x may get you started.

Comment: @freakish what are you trying to test? The pool limits are just limits,they don't affect the number of available or active threads. Use `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads()` if you want to see how many threads are available. Start some tasks to force more to be created. Again though, those limits aren't meant to restrict the number of concurrent operations, that's what the TaskScheduler parameters are for. They won't restrict *async IO* operations since they don't use user-mode threads

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Obviously single-thread ThreadPool is useful for testing the behaviour under single thread without code refactorization. I'm not looking for alternative ways, the refactoring of the real code may be too costly. Besides whether this is useful or not is just an opinion. I shouldn't comment on it at all. And `ps -M` **is** the tool for the job simply because it tells me the truth about my process. Since I don't know what exactly happens under the hood I can be fairly sure that everything is OK if I see only one thread.

Comment: @freakish, I repeat, that's the job of the *TaskScheduler*, which can be injected to any operation. You can use different schedulers for different operations if you want. The ThreadPool is a *global* service though, totally unsuitable for async testing since the *test* code will also use it. You can't use it as an alternative to the TaskScheduler

Comment: @freakish if you want to know what's going on under the hood, you can check the source code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Right, reading the source code. That's a great tip. Everything is in the source code, why do we need SO anyway? :D Back to the topic: it seems that even if I run a simple single threaded app (as in just `Thread.Sleep(10000);` in Main) I still see background threads. Is there no way to run single threaded app in C#/.net core?

Comment: @freakish yes, [reading the CLR source code and chasing the calls](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L594). You'll see that calls from ThreadPool.cs are passed directly to the runtime. Which also means that the size of the threadpool doesnt' affect async operations *directly*. That [runtime code shows](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp#L619) that the runtime won't try to *close* working threads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) state:

> You cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion
>   threads to a number smaller than the number of processors on the
>   computer.

*Given you have 8 processors, you therefore cannot set it to only one.*

Additionally, calling:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1, 1);
```

doesn't limit your **process** to a single thread (even if it let you set it to 1, which it won't since 1 is less than 8). It just limits the size of the **Thread Pool**. The program can (and will) still use more than one thread.

For example, the GC will likely run on a separate thread. Or you may create your own separate thread (without using the Thread Pool). Limiting the maximum size of the Thread Pool won't impact that.